# react native vs flutter ,should i move from react-native to flutter

Tags: react-native, flutter

i am react native developer , and my question is more generic than code

i am getting really frustrated with react native and the amount of bugs it has
and the extremely low performance on android devices specially the old ones
almost all of the important api are third party developed on github and  they not maintained anymore with alot of bugs.
some codes doesn't work sometimes,
what i noticed with highly used(10k+ users) application in react native

- on **some** android devices fetch request is repeated 4 times.
- on some android devices async-storage is working probably .
- on await and async are getting ignored
- React.usestate is buggy and it is ignored sometimes

does flutter offer a better environment with less bugs

Comment: Please Review your code. Problem is not with react-native your code has bugs.

Comment: Please don't ask opinion-based questions in SO

Comment: so you are telling my flatlist isnot buggy, or image provided by react native is so amazing which deals with images as a browser

Comment: touchable opacity getting clicked multiple times  on one click __ i am talking about general bugs that are encountered with react native,will i face them if i move to flutter or not

Answer (score 3):

Speaking from personal experience, flutter is better than react native for several reasons, but I'll list the few best ones here:-

1. More interactice community :- Flutter has way more answered question in the past 2 years on stackoverflow than react
2. Better docs - The flutter docs cover everything, I mean everything\
3. Nativeness - Flutter does a great job at making the app look as native to the platform as possible
4. Wide range of packages - Like it says, there is a package for everything, You can also use platform views just in case there is something on the native side you want to add so there are no limits
5. The editors - OMg I cannot say how much easier it is with good descriptions of all the commands within the code. I mean you can hover on a function and if made by the flutter team or a proper package team, you'll see the full implementation
6. Rid of any form of html or css - The designing, is much much much much much * infinity easier because everything makes just more sense from a programmer's poin t of view
7. Great debugging - With flutter, you can debug on different scales, even on the release scale just in case there is a problem with release mode instead of debug mode and ofcourse the community is always there to help
8. Regular awesome updates - While react is slowly dying down on new features, flutter is booming. With the recent update to flutter 2.0 introducing null safety, the chance of bugs have gone down even more

So yes, I recommend you try to shift to flutter. There is even a full tutorial in the flutter docs for react-native decs to learn flutter.